# Using a variable from another class Swift

Tags: swift

This is probably super simple and I am just missing something. I am trying to check if the view is loaded and visisble. Two edge cases, if it is visible, I just update a string inside the class, if it is not visable, I present the class. I tried to use .isViewLoaded on the class from another class and always got false returned. So I tried just have an initial value on the class that just gets updated is viewDidAppear gets called, but when accessing that value from another class I get no luck. Could anyone help here

```
class TimeController: UIViewController {

var openingTimeValue: String = ""
var timeShown: Bool = false

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
       return self.timeShown = true
}

override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    return self.timeShown = false
}
```

This is the class where I am setting the values and am trying to update when view is shown^

```
                if self.timeController.timeShown == true {
                self.timeController.openingTimeValue = timeUntilOpen
                return
            } else {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                _ = self.presentWeAreClosed(opensIn: timeUntilOpen)
            }
```

This is the class I always get false from. I originally tried to do this.

```
                if self.timeController.isViewLoaded
```

But still got false. I know it is something to do with inheritance which is what I'm still trying to get my head around in Swift. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At some point you'll need to declare a delegate on the **TimeController** then it can tell your class what the value is. We could do this inversely too, and have **MyClass** conform to a protocol that retrieves the value when needed.

```
protocol TimeReporter {
  func report(isShown: Bool)
}

class TimeController: UIViewController {

  var openingTimeValue: String = ""
  var timeShown: Bool = false {
    didSet(newValue) {
      delegate?.report(isShown: newValue)
    }
  }

  var delegate: TimeReporter?

  override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    timeShown = true
  }

  override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    timeShown = false
  }

}

class MyClass: TimeReporter {

  var reported: Bool? 

  func setReporter() {
    guard let vc = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController as? TimeController else { return }
    vc.delegate = self
  }

  func report(isShown: Bool) {
    reported = isShown

    // call your behavior here, or just store the new value.
    if (isShown) {
      self.timeController.openingTimeValue = timeUntilOpen
    } else {
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.presentWeAreClosed(opensIn: timeUntilOpen)
      }
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer, I'm still getting false for some reason, I believe the didSet is not working for me. Doens't seem to be changing to true on viewDidAppear

Comment: The Class there which is called MyClass, the value is always false. For some reason I cannot seem to get the values that is being set through the protocol

Comment: How are you creating the TimeController?? Is it the root of your app?

Comment: No, it's just a presented view controller on its own from my rootViewController which is a tabBarController. Im just calling the present on it

Comment: So you have a reference of TimeController in the interface builder, a tabBarController is the root of the app? Or are you programmatically creating the tabs? Is TimeController the first view in the tabBarController? Do you also have a NavigationController embedded in the TimeController?

Comment: I've actually built the app using UIKit without IB, I think you are giving my ideas though of what I've done incorrectly.

Comment: guard let vc = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController as? TimeController else { return } I guess this shouldn't be right as TimeController is not my RootView,

Comment: Right, you'll need to find where you create the TimeController and give the controller instance your **MyClass** instance as a delegate. But I worry that a navigationController is also eating your **viewDidAppear()**.

Comment: TimeController is its own view entirely. Just a UIViewController with nothing wrapped around it, I am just doing a present() inside my moobTabs UITabBarController to overlay the whole screen. The issue is (I believe) the delegate is not being passed correctly and I am always getting false. Which I believe is down to the above. if the view is on its own could I do something like 

UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.TimeController or something like that.

Comment: Find where you're doing the present, and pull out the instance of TimeController. You'll want to assign the delegate property of the TimeController to your MyClass instance. Then pass the same instance of TimeController to your present call.

Comment: Also feel free, to post your present call, then I can write it for you in my answer too.

Comment: ````func presentWeAreClosed(opensIn: String) -> String {
        let timeController = TimeController()
        let text = opensIn
        timeController.openingTimeValue = text
        self.present(timeController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        return text
    }````

Comment: Where do you create the *MyClass* instance? Do you have access to it at this point in your app?

Comment: let timeController = TimeController(); timeController.delegate = MyClass(); let text = ........

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modally an active controller <myApp.moonTabs: 0x7f8494003000>.' Mate we are deffo getting somewhere, I'm now getting an actual error :D

Comment: ````func presentWeAreClosed(opensIn: String) -> String {
        let text = opensIn
        timeController.delegate = moonTabs()
        timeController.openingTimeValue = text
        self.present(timeController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        return text
    }````

Comment: Also dude, send me your wallet address or some form of donation, happy to give your some cash for helping me with this

Comment: We may need to dismiss a view controller then in the completion, present the TimeController again.

Comment: All sorted mate, thank you so so much! Really need to get my head around this protocol thing in Swift :D Legend dude